# How can I install Gamescope on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: software-installation, games

I want to install the lastest version of [gamescope](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/gamescope) on Ubuntu 23.10 but all the PPAs do not seem to support it.

Answer (score 1):

To install gamescope on Ubuntu 23.10, you can follow these steps:

1. Clone the source from the official GitHub repository:

   ```bash
   git clone https://github.com/ValveSoftware/gamescope.git
   ```
2. Install the required dependencies using the following command:

   ```bash
   sudo apt install libavif15 libbenchmark1debian libdisplay-info1 libevdev-dev libgav1-1 libgudev-1.0-dev libmtdev-dev libseat1 libstb0 libwacom-dev libxcb-ewmh2 libxcb-shape0-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev libxmu-headers libyuv0 libx11-xcb-dev libxres-dev libxmu-dev libseat-dev libinput-dev libxcb-composite0-dev libxcb-ewmh-dev libxcb-icccm4-dev libxcb-res0-dev libcap-dev
   ```
3. Run the following commands to initialize the submodules and build `gamescope`:

   ```bash
   cd gamescope
   git submodule update --init
   meson build/
   ninja -C build/
   ```
4. You can now test if the binary works correctly:

   ```bash
   build/src/gamescope -- vkcube
   ```
5. If `gamescope` worked fine, you can install it on your system like with the following command:

   ```bash
   meson install -C build/ --skip-subprojects
   ```

Comment: I'm having the same issue - I can't build under Ubuntu 23.10 because meson says that I'm missing a bunch of libraries.  I ran the apt command you gave, though, and it says that they're all installed.  Why wouldn't meson detect the different libraries?